# sql to SUM the USERS sales

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, sgl

I am trying to make a sql where I have 2 tables, one users and sales, my idea is to be able to make a ranking of the users who have made the most sales by date.

sql sellers users

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuario 
WHERE usuario_tipo_id =3
```

Sql sales according to date and sale status

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sale 
WHERE usuario_id=49 
  and venta_fecha between '12/05/2020' and '13/05/2020' 
  AND sale_estado =2
```

What is the effective way to join these queries in order to get a list ordered by the amount of sales of the user

```
usuario | sales
user1   | 10
user 6  |  8
user 2  | 3
```

gracias

Comment: Please translate to english or move to an appropriate so site for your language. Also add your mysql version.

Comment: already translated, thanks

Comment: Rank has meaning in sql - you don't rank here you are just ordering by sales desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like

```
SELECT usuario.name usuario, SUM(sale.sales) total_sales
FROM usuario
JOIN sale ON usuario.id = sale.usuario_id /* or usuario.usuario_tipo_id? */
WHERE sale.venta_fecha between '12/05/2020' and '13/05/2020' 
  AND sale.sale_estado =2
GROUP BY usuario.name
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm making some assumptions.. but it probably is something along the lines of this using a left inner join to join the two tables. This makes sure the join doesn't result in NULL values:

```
SELECT 
  u.nome
  , SUM(s.order_total) AS total 
FROM 
  usuario u 
    LEFT INNER JOIN sale s 
      ON u.usuario_id = s.usuario_id 
WHERE 
  s.venta_fecha BETWEEN '12/05/2020' 
    AND '13/05/2020' 
GROUP BY 
  u.nome 
ORDER BY 
  SUM(s.order_total) DESC;
```